# Enterprise Library 5.0 with ODP.NET causing ORA-06502 error

Tags: vb.net, oracle, enterprise-library, odp.net

I'm getting a strange error when using Enterprise Library 5.0 with EntLibContrib.Data.OdpNet added.

When i try to run a package, I am getting an ORA-06502 error.  When i try and run the package using standard ODP.NET and using OracleDataTypes instead of the generic DbTypes, it works fine.

I tried turning Number parameters to DbType.Decimal and Varchar2 to DbType.String.  I've also experimented with VarNumeric (can't convert apparently) and AnsiString.  I keep failing to get the package to run.

Here's the signature of the package:

```
procedure process_Something(
    o_param1            OUT VARCHAR2,   
    o_param2            OUT VARCHAR2,   
    in_ID1              IN  NUMBER,     
    in_ID2              IN  NUMBER,     
    in_UNIQUE1          IN  VARCHAR2,   
    in_STR_PARAM1       IN  VARCHAR2,
    in_STR_PARAM2       IN  VARCHAR2,
    in_STR_PARAM3       IN  VARCHAR2,
    in_STR_PARAM4       IN  VARCHAR2,
    in_STR_PARAM5       IN  VARCHAR2,
    in_NUM_PARAM        IN  NUMBER,     
    in_STR_PARAM6       IN  VARCHAR2,
    in_STR_PARAM7       IN  VARCHAR2,
    in_STR_PARAM8       IN  VARCHAR2,
    in_STR_PARAM9       IN  VARCHAR2,
    in_STR_PARAM10      IN  VARCHAR2,
);
```

Here's the code i am using to call it.:

```
      var oComm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("APPS.MY_PACKAGE.process_Something");
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_ID1", DbType.Decimal, int.Parse(item.ID1));
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_ID2", DbType.Decimal, int.Parse(item.ID2));
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_UNIQUE1", DbType.String, item.Unique1.Trim());
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_STR_PARAM1", DbType.String, item.STR_Param1.Trim());
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_STR_PARAM2", DbType.String, item.STR_Param2.Trim());
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_STR_PARAM3", DbType.String, item.STR_Param3.Trim());
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_STR_PARAM4", DbType.String, item.STR_Param4.Trim());
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_STR_PARAM5", DbType.String, item.STR_Param5.Trim());
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_NUM_PARAM", DbType.Decimal, int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.NumParam.Trim()) ? "0" : item.NumParam));
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_STR_PARAM6", DbType.String, item.STR_Param6.Trim());
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_STR_PARAM7", DbType.String, string.Empty);
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_STR_PARAM8", DbType.String, item.STR_Param8.Trim());
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_STR_PARAM9", DbType.String, item.STR_Param9.Trim());
      db.AddInParameter(oComm, "in_STR_PARAM10", DbType.String, item.STR_Param10.Trim());
      db.AddOutParameter(oComm, "o_param1", DbType.String, 200);
      db.AddOutParameter(oComm, "o_param2", DbType.String, 200);
      db.ExecuteNonQuery(oComm);
```